# react hook form: useFieldArray circular reference type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I am trying to use the `useFieldArray` hook from `react-hook-form` with an object that has a recursive type definition. However, this causes a type error:

```
Type of property 'children' circularly references itself in mapped type '{ [K in keyof TOrganization]-?: ArrayPathImpl<K & string, TOrganization[K]>; }'.ts(2615)
```

I found a solution to this problem in [this issue](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/4055), but I don't understand it. Can someone help me understand the solution or provide an alternative solution?

Thank for your help.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-ganguly-ee6ef6)